# How to cast HASHLIB digest to array in python?

Tags: python, hashlib

I'm trying to compare the result of an `SHA1` digest to an initialized array.

But when comparing the first byte, it returns that they are not equal, while when printing the first byte of the digest, it's the same as the first byte in my initialized array.

Should I cast it somehow?

```
import hashlib


my_digest = [0x7,0x3,0x8,0x2,0x2,0x5,0x6,0xa,0xb,0xb,0x3,0xe,0xe,0xa,0x3,0x2,0x5,0xf,0x9,0xa,0xd,0xe,0x1,0xc,0xc,0x0,0x4,0xe,0x4,0x9,0x3,0x3,0xe,0xe,0x8,0x1,0x7,0xc,0xd,0x3]
digest = hashlib.sha1(b"im a very good speaker").hexdigest()
# digest = 7382256abb3eea325f9ade1cc04e4933ee817cd3

if(digest[0] == my_digest[0]):
    print("correct")
else:
    print("not correct")
print(digest)
```

---

**output :**

```
not correct
7382256abb3eea325f9ade1cc04e4933ee817cd3
```

`print(digest[0])` return 7

Comment: To start with, `7382...` is not `[0x7, 0x3, ...`, but `[0x73, 0x82, ...`

Comment: when printing digest[0], it returns 0x7, not 0x72

Comment: @mikmik are you using Python 2?

Comment: Because `digest` is a hexdump, i.e. a string representation of a byte array. Try `digest()` instead of `hexdigest()` and you'll get raw bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want to represent the digest as a list of hex integers, it will look like this:

```
>>> my_digest = [0x73, 0x82, 0x25, 0x6a, 0xbb, 0x3e, 0xea, 0x32, 0x5f, 0x9a, 0xde, 0x1c, 0xc0, 0x4e, 0x49, 0x33, 0xee, 0x81, 0x7c, 0xd3]
```

Second, you want `digest()` instead of `hexdigest()` to get the raw bytes hash:

```
>>> digest = hashlib.sha1(b"im a very good speaker").digest()
```

Finally, convert it to list before comparison:

```
>>> list(digest) == my_digest
True
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Python 3**, with your code you are comparing `str` with `int` and while this can be done, it would not try to interpret the content of the string, so `'7' != 7`.

One way to circumvent this is to *cast* your `int` to `str`, e.g.:

```
if digest[0] == str(my_digest[0]):
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the `type`. You are comparing a string to an int. See below for a possible fix.

```
import hashlib

my_digest = [0x7,0x3,0x8,0x2,0x2,0x5,0x6,0xa,0xb,0xb,0x3,0xe,0xe,0xa,0x3,0x2,0x5,0xf,0x9,0xa,0xd,0xe,0x1,0xc,0xc,0x0,0x4,0xe,0x4,0x9,0x3,0x3,0xe,0xe,0x8,0x1,0x7,0xc,0xd,0x3]
digest = hashlib.sha1(b"im a very good speaker").hexdigest()
# digest = 7382256abb3eea325f9ade1cc04e4933ee817cd3

print("digest[0]", type(digest[0]))
print("my_digest[0]", type(my_digest[0]))

if(int(digest[0]) == my_digest[0]):
    print("correct")
else:
    print("not correct")
print(digest)
```

Comment: I got an issue when comparing 0xa : `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'`

Comment: @mikmik Oh sorry I was trying to explain why `digest[0] == my_digest[0]` was giving you output `not correct`